# "Interner Explore has stop working" Getting a issue in IE 11 When user tab on html number input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, internet-explorer

I have one issue regarding IE 11 when i tab on html number input internet Explorer get close.I am using input type="number" and also using a angular directive "string-to-number".
I am writing my code and also displaying a error.

My Html code

```
<input type="number"  string-to-number name="txtNum" autocomplete="off" ng-model="NumModel" ng-min="0.00" ng-max="999.99" />
```

Error Message while tab to control

[image]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Narrow down the scope of your problem. As it is, tabbing into an HTML5 number input does not crash IE11. So, it must be something else. Try removing the directive and then see. Try removing Javascript associated with the previous input (*from where you are tabbing out*) and then see. Keep on removing things until you get to a point where the problem no longer occurs. Then you will know more-or-less what piece is causing the problem, and then come back here with those details.

Comment: @Abhitalks thanks your suggestion help me to solve some other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to comment by @Abhitalks, try also adding some attributes. Like adding placeholder. Sounds silly but sometimes it may works! :)

Comment: Thanks, Adding blank placeholder do the trick, Some time silly thing work like a charm.. :)